# How to pass a value to a function and then return a new one?

Tags: python, function

```
def print_kart(kart):
    for rad in kart:
         print("   ".join(rad))

def oppdater_kart(spillerX, spillerY, monsterX, monsterY):
    kart = []
    gridline = []
    for y in range(10):
      gridline.append(".")

    for x in range(10):
     kart.append(list(gridline))

    kart[spillerY][spillerX]= '\U0001f600' #smiley
    kart[monsterY][monsterX] = '\U0001f47A' #goblin
    print_kart(kart)


def flytt_spiller(bevegelse, spillerX, spillerY):
    if bevegelse == "w":
        spillerY -=1

    elif bevegelse == "a":
        spillerX -=1

    elif bevegelse == "s":
        spillerY +=1

    elif bevegelse == "d":
        spillerX +=1

    else:
        print('push wasd to move  ')

    return spillerY, spillerX


def oppgave4():

    spillerX=1
    spillerY=2
    monsterX=3
    monsterY=4
    oppdater_kart(spillerX, spillerY, monsterX, monsterY)

    bevegelse = input('move: ')

    flytt_spiller(bevegelse, spillerX, spillerY)
    oppdater_kart(spillerX, spillerY, monsterX, monsterY)


oppgave4()
```

So I'm trying to implement `flytt_spiller()` in `oppgave4()` so that the smiley moves according to the `input(w/a/s/d)`.

How can i get the value `spillerX/spillerY` into `flytt_spiller()`, then change it, and then return a new value to `oppgave4()` ?

Comment: Well first, you're not implementing `flytt_spiller` there, you're just calling it. Second, you can get the value returned by a function and assign it to a variable. `spillerX, spillerY = flytt_spiller(...)`

Comment: use while loop and make a new argument to exit

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a condition to stop your code and till that condition is not meet then run the existing code in non stop

```
def oppgave4():

    spillerX=1
    spillerY=2
    monsterX=3
    monsterY=4
    exit = 10

    oppdater_kart(spillerX, spillerY, monsterX, monsterY)

    bevegelse = int(input('move: '))
    while bevegelse!=10:
        flytt_spiller(bevegelse, spillerX, spillerY)
        oppdater_kart(spillerX, spillerY, monsterX, monsterY)
        bevegelse = int(input('move: '))
```